# Prelude.head: empty list in if statement

Tags: function, haskell, if-statement, runtime-error, empty-list

I'm writing a function and it throws `Prelude.head empty list` if I use the variable `newBoard` where I have `sortBoard` in the if-else it throws this error. If I use the original `board` character it doesn't throw this error.

```
foo :: [[Char]] -> [(Int, Int)] -> [(Int, (Int, Int))] -> Int -> [(Int,Int)]-> [Int]-> [[Char]]
foo [] _ _ _ _ _ = []
foo board [] _ _ _ [] = board
foo board spot array number startArray move = nextStep
    where 
        newBoard        = set board (head spot) ('1')
        tailSpot        = tail spot
        nextStep = 
            if tailSpot == []
                then if (tail move) == []
                        then newBoard
                    else sortBoard newBoard array 1 [] (tail move)
            else (foo newBoard tailSpot array 1 [] move)
```

For explination on this code, I have a game board and need to enter '1' in certain spots which are given by the variable `spot`. If I have gone through all the spots(`tailSpot`) and there are no more sections I need to change(`move`) it should just return the new board. If I still have sections I need to change, I exit this function and go back to finding the spots in that section so I can come back and switch them. If I still have a section and spots left, I keep going through this function until all spots are changed.

Comment: Using `head` and `tail` is inherently dangerous, and very rarely needed - I'd avoid them as much as reasonably possible. Replace them with pattern matching, and turn on warnings with `-Wall` so that GHC can warn about missed cases.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here:

```
newBoard        = set board (head spot) ('1')
```

You're calling `head` on `spot` list. But `spot` may be empty list. Your pattern matching is non-exhaustive enough. Here `foo board [] _ _ _ [] = board` you check that `spot` and `move` both empty simultaneosly. While one of them may be empty while the other one has at least one element.

Try to structure your code in more modular manner making imposible states unrepresentable. Most likely your code can be refactored to avoid situations when only one list is empty, if one one of two can happen: both lists are empty or both has at least one element.

Comment: Do you know how I can make it exhaustive? I tried to have pattern matching with `foo board [] _ _ _ _ = sortBoard...` and another `food board _ _ _ _ [] = board` but it said pattern match was redundant. I've been looking at this code for days and can't come up with anything.

Comment: @JessSmith try this set of patterns. `ghc` doesn't warn me about redundant pattern matchings here http://lpaste.net/1351820791544545280